# How do I set a scrollbar-gutter on the page only if there is a scrollbar?

Tags: css

I have a website were some pages are long enough that there is a vertical scrollbar on the body, and some pages are too short to have one.

I also have a dialog boxes on my website which disable scrolling by setting `overflow-y: hidden` on the document element.

In order to prevent layout shifts when the dialogs are opened and the scrollbar is removed, I want to use `scrollbar-gutter: stable`.

However, in the cases were scrollbar gutter is applied to pages which aren`t long enough to have a scrollbar, you still get the gutter which of course causes the page look weird.

Therefore I need a way to only apply the scrollbar gutter if the page can have a scrollbar. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect it with simple JavaScript.

```
if (document.body.scrollHeight > window.innerHeight) {
    document.body.classList.add('has-scroll')
}
```

But I don't recommend you to use scrollbar-gutter since Safari does not support it.
Instead you can try to play with width: 100vw, thats way your page will always have constant width.

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
}

.some-element-with-position-fixed {
    width: 100vw;
}
```